# Use external REST API with ReactJS and NodeJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, rest

I am still learning about ReactJS and NodeJS.

My devs have created a boilerplate with create-react-app 
We have an External REST API service , and we want to make calls (GET, PUT ...) to their APIs and retrieve and put data.

My question is, ReactJS can also consume REST APIs (external ones, from another web site). Why do I need NodeJS then? I think ideal would be that NodeJS makes those calls for ReactJS and makes server side rendering.

What is the best practice here with this stack. I do not need (or maybe do I?) to buld internal APIs with ExpressJS, since I have external ones from another web service provider which retrieves data for me out of their data store.

Can someone elaborate on the best practice here ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If in future you think you will have to build internal APIs which may not consume the external APIs then have an API layer. There are lot of factors. I personally would suggest to have an API server anyhow. At a very high level if in case you need to change the third party API service provider your API layer should be able to handle it. There is also a possibility that in future you may have to integrate more third party API providers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React can easily make API calls. this is typically done through componentDidMount method or in useEffect if using hooks.

You can of course use a backend to make these requests too like you said with NodeJS. but whether you do or don't is completely up to you and your use case

typically you would use NodeJS and a backend to help separate out logic, especially if you need to make calls to a database and stuff.

another good reason would be if you are handling sensitive information you would want to do this server side and not client side.

so in summary, it's completely up to you and what you need. personally I use react with lambda/api gateway in aws to separate logic out

example node js endpoint (returning an array to react)

```
app.get('/api/my-route', (req, res, next) => {
    const array = [1,2,3,4,5]
    res.json(array)
})
```

Comment: Thanks. I understood , that it would be good to buiild my own API with for an example ExpressJS as an API layer that talks to the external API and leaves me options and is best practice. I would like to use NodeJS as backend, but how can I connect it with ReactJS, so that ReactJS triggers the NodeJS external API calls (the routes and endpoints in NodeJS are needed to be built first?)

Comment: yeh you should build the routes in express. then simply get react to hit those endpoints. you can use a thing called proxy in package.json so that react can hit your endpoints. look here for more info: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/

Comment: Thanks . You mean I need to build my Express  API with routes .And React hits those endpoints. But how can I tell ExpressJS to call REST Api Calls, like just to make http call to the External API ?

Comment: yeh do something like this `app.get('/api/route', (req, res, next) => { // logic in here` then if you use proxy above you should be able to go to `localhost:9000/api/route`

Comment: Great. This is what I was thinking. So when you wrote //logic in here, I assume this is the logic to call the REST API from the external API site and then return the vaules or PUT, POST the values. What is your best practice here.? Which modules? I was using before like this: function(req, res) {
  var request = require('request'); var options = {
  'method': 'GET',
request(options, function (error, response) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);
  console.log(response.body);
  res.send(response.body);
});
});
 do you have some examples onlinne maybe ? Github ?

Comment: yeh exactly put all your API request logic in there. there are plenty of node js API examples/tutorials online if you google that. I'll add an example to my question you can see use too

Comment: @ultimo_frogman check now. that is just going to return an array in the response to the frontend when you hit that route but of course the world is your oyster when it comes to what logic you could put in there, make api requests/do anything basically

Comment: @ultimo_frogman let me know if you need any more help or if you can accept the answer that would be great :)

Comment: Hi. I am still thinking how can I use best the logic to call the external API , with fetch from NodeJS or some modules ?

Comment: fetch is best or use axios. either do the job fine. I think I have answered your specific question but feel free to post another one on something more specific and I can try and help you answer that one too :)

Comment: You mean, in the NodeJS I can use Axios for the Logic? I think I have seen that this needs to be done in ReactJS

Comment: nope you can do it in either. it really depends what you want to do. node is just javascript at the end of the day so you can use npm packages with it. or just use the inbuilt fetch. feel free to ask another specific question about how you do an axios request in node and I can answer that. or if you want assistance making API calls in react. then ask that. but ultimately you can do it in both and it depends entirely on where you want to take your application.

Comment: there should be a tick next to my answer and if you can click the up arrow too that would be great! I will click the up arrow for you too so you get some more rep :)

Comment: Thanks. One more if I can. https://github.com/CodementorIO/nextjs-redux-starter what would you recommend as a start generator for that ExpressJs, Redux, React Web app

Comment: I've not used nextjs before. but I've heard it's very good. I normally use CRA: https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html. then build the server with Express and if you need state management there are a few tools but the best one imo is Redux.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for you answer. I have been taking a look at the MVC concepts of ExpressJS and Typescript(do not want to tackle to much TS if not needed) and DomainDriven Design here. https://khalilstemmler.com/articles/typescript-domain-driven-design/repository-dto-mapper/   For me it makes sense to use json.stringify and to separate the logic of the GET/PUT thirdparty API responses into my web app. Do you have some pointers here , did you use this approach to build the ExpressJS API.

Comment: it sounds like you have the right idea. if you want a more detailed answer I suggest asking another question around this as I have limited space I can answer with now. but it sounds like you have the right approach. and yeh Typescript is good to learn but I would learn pure JS and react first and when you feel comfortable introduce TS.